# AWS RDS db creation limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-rds-data-service

I need to migrate to RDS from our current server. Our application automatically created dbs according to its need. since the rds have a default dB create  limit of 40, is it possible to automatically increase the quota to more than 100. ? And also is there any extra change that we need to look into.

Comment: Are you referring to databases _within_ the Amazon RDS database? That is, databases that are created via the `CREATE DATABASE` command? Or are you referring to database instances (separate Amazon RDS databases)? If it is the latter, why would you need so many databases? It does not sounds like an efficient use of resources.

Answer (score 1):

> If your application requires more DB instances, you can request
> additional DB instances by opening the [Service Quotas console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1#!/dashboard). In the
> navigation pane, choose AWS services. Choose Amazon Relational
> Database Service (Amazon RDS), choose a quota and follow the
> directions to request a quota increase. For more information, see
> [Requesting a Quota Increase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/latest/userguide/request-increase.html) in the Service Quotas User Guide.

Refer to [the AWS document][3]

Comment: do they take any extra charge for additional dbs?

Comment: Not at all. but like John mention before. Do you need a DB instance or just DB inside the instance? Please consider carefully

Comment: I need to create individual dbs within the instance.

Comment: @TuanVo please re-link the correct AWS document to your answer.